# How do I install a program for a non administrator so that it appears in his activities?

Tags: gnome

I made an account for my wife where she has non administrator privileges.
Among the music programs which she needs is Rosegarden.
There are 2 problems:

1. None of the programs I install for her appear in her Activities screen.
   She can search for them, but I assume she won't remember what the names are for searching.
   Here is what the search shows:
   [image: activitives]
2. Rosegarden cannot be made a favorite

[image: favorite]

What can I do to help her? If I log in user her user name, I have no sudo commands.
I can still access her files from my account where sudo exists.
Clearly I won't be able to change applications in her activities screen from my account.

Edit: to correct the desktop file, I added the line (but it didn't help):

```
StartupWMClass="Rosegarden"
```

Looking glass gave me

```
Untitled - Rosegarden
wmclass Rosegarden
<untracked>
```

Edit2: I still don't understand what exactly causes an application to become visible in Activities without it being searched for. I thought perhaps there is a program which might scan on startup, so I put rosegarden on the desktop and pinned Qsynth and Qjack to the favorites bar.

Then I logged off, and even tried to power down, but they still remain invisible in Activities (without doing a search). So that remains a mystery, but at least my wife has enough to work without being forced to remember program names. Perhaps in time the programs will become magically visible???

Likewise I can forward a link to this discussion to the rosegarden developers so they have a good idea what needs to be fixed. What I did fix is a good start but not sufficient.

Thanks in advance for all advice.

Comment: Are there .desktop files for these apps in `/usr/share/applications`?

Comment: Are you really using unity? Isn't that Gnome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Rosegarden cannot be made a favorite

Contact the developers of rosegarden. They need to fix how the software is executed, and may need to fix the .desktop file.

---

However, you can put an application launcher in your desktop.

Copy the .desktop file to your desktop (do this from your wife's account, you won't need sudo).

```
cp /usr/share/applications/com.rosegardenmusic.rosegarden.desktop ~/Desktop/
chmod +x ~/Desktop/com.rosegardenmusic.rosegarden.desktop
```

Now it should show up in the desktop (as an application launcher).

Comment: Thanks for making my question clearer, and for all your help. In order to learn I wanted to take your commands one at a time and look at the details. The cp to ~/Desktop/ does the copy but no icon appears on my desktop. I even tried log out, log in and still nothing. I agree with your idea of, for now, let's put the icon on the desktop since I can't make it a favorite.

Comment: There is another problem though, which I didn't mention in order to keep the question short. There are several support programs like qsynth and qjack, which also do no appear directly in her activities, but can be made favorites once they are launched. I would like a way to log into her account and make icons visible WITHOUT needing to search for them. It seems that when I created her account, all applications were copied to her activities, but any applications which I installed afterwards were NOT added without the search stage. So I need to know what config file I need to modify so they appe

Comment: One work around for activities is to delete my wife as a user, with all of her data and then recreate her. This is ugly and I don't really learn how to solve the problem for the next round of things.

Comment: I think you deserve credit for the fix, even if the Activities part still remains unsolved. See my edit for details.

Answer (score 3):

That Rosegarden cannot be pinned is likely due to the fact that the shell cannot associate the running window with the icon. That can happen if the WM_CLASS of the spawned window is quite different.

**Correcting the desktop launcher**

Copy the .desktop file over to `~/.local/share/applications`(for change at the user level) or to `/usr/local/share/applications` (if you want to change for all users) and open that copy in a text editor (in the latter directory, you need root permissions).

Add a line like

```
StartupWMClass=<WM_Class>
```

where you substitute `<WM_Class>` by the actual window class of the running application.

**Determining the WMClass**

Launch the program and

If you are on **Xorg**: run the command `xprop WM_CLASS`. You need the second string, e.g. in `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "firefox"`, you need `firefox`.

If you are in Gnome Shell on **Wayland**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `lg` then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and, in the "looking glass", find the window and the class on hte Windows tab.

After these changes, the shell will associate the running application with the correct launcher, and you will be able to pin it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I found on Wayland that I needed Rosegarden. I edited my question to show the change.